# Homeomorphism of the unit disk fixes the unit circle

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to solve this problem

> Suppose $f : D \rightarrow D$ is a homeomorphism, then $f(S^1)=S^1$.

I really dont know how to tackle this problem , i started trying to prove it by contradiction  but i dont  know how to go from there. Any tips are appreciated, just want a few advices to get the exercise started.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide more context: Which theorems and methods do you know? For example the fundamental group?

Comment: Yes i am familiar with fundamental groups, homotopy types,and the basic theorems of covering spaces and  the seifert van kampen theorem, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $f(S^1) \ne S^1$. Then $f(S^1) \not\subset S^1$ or $S^1 \not\subset f(S^1)$. It suffices to consider the case $f(S^1) \not\subset S^1$ because in the other case we have $f^{-1}(S^1) \not\subset S^1$ and we can consider the homeomorphism $f^{-1}$ instead of $f$.

Some $x_0 \in S^1$ is mapped to $y_0 = f(x_0) \in \Delta = D \setminus S^1$. Hence $f$ establishes a homeomorphism $f' : D \setminus \{x_0\} \to D \setminus \{y_0\}$. But $D \setminus \{x_0\}$ is contractible (radial contraction to $0$) and $D \setminus \{y_0\}$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, thus the two spaces cannot be homeomorphic (consider e.g. fundamental groups).

Comment: Alright, that all makes sense i just need to clear some things, first when you say that $D-{x_0}$ is contractible, it is equivalent to saying that it is homotopic to a point, why is this true ? is the space convex ?(im not quite sure cause we removed a point). The other part that $D-{y_0}$ is homotopic equivalent to $S^1$ we just need to do a translation from the point to $0$ and then do the obvious function that is dividing by the norm right?

Comment: The space $D \setminus \{x_0\}$ is star-shaped (with center $0)$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain. For $D \setminus \{y_0\}$ you are right.

Comment: I corrected a mistake: I used the symbol $\subsetneqq$ instead of $\not\subset$.

Comment: Alright , thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

A more elementary proof uses homotopies. That is, you  can also get a contradiction by observing that homeomorphisms preserve simple-connectedness: if $f:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism, and $X$ is simply connected, then it's easy to show that $Y$ is path connected, so fixing a point $y_0\in Y$, and taking any loop $\ell:I\to Y$ at $y_0$, we have that $f^{-1}\circ \ell$ is a loop in $X$, and since $X$ is contractible, there is a homotopy $H$ from $f^{-1}\circ \ell$ to $f^{-1}(y_0)$. Then, $f\circ H$ is a homotopy from $\ell$ to $y_0$, so $Y$ is contractible.